# No logro actualizar más de un objeto en el método update

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

Tengo este archivo JSON:

```
{
   "client": "Medine",
   "payment_term" : "Lorem ipsu",
   "creation_date" : "2021-05-06",
   "created_by" : "testing",
   "state" : "active",
   "observation" : "ipsu lorem",
   "items" : [
       {
           "name" : "desktop",
           "amount" : 1,
           "price" : 600,
           "sub_total" : 600
       },
       {
           "name" : "cccc",
           "amount" : 1,
           "price" : 600,
           "sub_total" : 600
       }
    ]
}
```

Toda la colección se guarda en 2 tablas que tengo relacionadas como 1 a muchos. Por su lado, hasta la propiedad "observations", se guarda en una tabla "sale_orders" y por el otro, el arreglo de objetos (**items**), se guardan en una tabla orderItems.

**El guardado lo hago de la siguiente manera y funciona perfecto** Primero hace el guardado en la tabla sale_orders y luego en la tabla order_items:

```
$sale_order = SaleOrder::create($request->all());
    $sale_order->save();

    $orderItems = [];

    foreach($request->items as $items){
        $orderItems[] = new OrderItem($items);
    }

    $sale_order->items()->saveMany($orderItems);
```

Mi **problema** es con el **método actualizar** ¿Cómo puedo actualizar cada objeto del arreglo de objetos "Items"? Ya que ahora le estoy enviando la colección, pero **cada item tiene su id**.

```
{
    "client": "Medine",
    "payment_term" : "Lorem ipsu",
    "creation_date" : "2021-05-06",
    "created_by" : "testing",
    "state" : "active",
    "observation" : "ipsu lorem",
    "items" : [
        {
            "id" : 1
            "name" : "desktop",
            "amount" : 1,
            "price" : 600,
            "sub_total" : 600
        },
        {
            "id" : 2
            "name" : "cccc",
            "amount" : 1,
            "price" : 600,
            "sub_total" : 600
        }
    ]
}
```

Hasta ahora, he desarrollado lo siguiente. Este ejemplo modifica los datos en sale_orders, pero en cuanto a los items, **solo modifica 1** Específicamente, el último que es recorrido por el foreach. Ojalá puedan ayudarme:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
       
    $sale_order = SaleOrder::find($id);
    $sale_order->client =  $request->client;
    $sale_order->payment_term = $request->payment_term;
    $sale_order->creation_date = $request->creation_date;
    $sale_order->created_by = $request->created_by;
    $sale_order->state = $request->state;
    $sale_order->observation = $request->observation;
    
    $sale_order->save();


    $orderItems = OrderItem::where('sale_order_id', $id)->first();
    foreach($request->items as $items){
        $orderItems->name = $items['name'];
        $orderItems->amount = $items['amount'];
        $orderItems->price = $items['price'];
        $orderItems->sub_total = $items['sub_total'];
    }
    $orderItems->save();


}
```

Comment: Buenas, Santiago, bienvenido al sitio. No tengo mucha idea de Laravel, pero ten en cuenta que el método first solo te devuelve un registro.  Si cambias la consulta OrderItem por un find para que recupera el item por su propio id, que estará en $items['id'], en lugar de por el de su venta y metes tanto esa consulta nueva como el save dentro del foreach, puede que te funcione.

Comment: solo te modifica el ultimo registro porque esta fuera del loop, cambia el $orderItems->save(); dentro del foreach

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas. Ambas tienen sentido y están en lo cierto. Al final, resolví pensando un poco más la lógica del problema ¿Me recomiendan editar la pregunta con mi solución?

Comment: Lo recomendado sería que respondieras a tu propia pregunta marcándola como respuesta acetada @SantiagoMedinaFiguera